# Are the sampled mean and variance approximations of population mean and variance?

Tags: inference, central-limit-theorem

Let's say that we have a population of 1000 people, and every day people eat some number of oranges. We run a survey to find how many oranges each individual has eaten in each of the last 360 days. We then bucket those 360 responses into 30-day periods, noting the mean and stdev for each, and mix them all into the same pool.

My question is a) is the mean value of the 30-day-bucket-means a valid approximation of the population mean of oranges per day? And b) is the mean value of the 30-day-bucket-variances a valid approximation of the population variance of oranges per day? I think they should be, because both the sampled means and sampled variances (ought to?) obey the central limit theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by a “valid” approximation? // Ai think you’re just giving an example, but I could see some issues related to the time series nature of the data, if this is really what you wanted to do. // Finite population corrections could be warranted, too. You don’t have to assume a finite population.

Comment: Your claim about the mean will hold by linearity of the expectation operator (here I assume that by 'valid' you want to know if it's an unbiased estimate of the mean). On the other hand, the Central Limit Theorem involves convergence of sample means to the population mean, but does not extend to arbitrary population parameters such as the variance.

Comment: @MarkoStojovic That would be the laws of large numbers, no?

Comment: @Dave Yes - sorry, that's what I was going for!

Comment: @MarkoStojovic is it correct to assume that the variance in oranges per day among members of the population is iid? If so, wouldn't the CLT hold for the mean of the reported variances?

Comment: @jefflovejapan Interesting challenge. Let's take X to be the number of oranges in a day. I agree that the sample variance is a random variable in its own right. As such, it converges to its population mean almost surely, by the Strong Law of Large Numbers. However, this does not imply that what it converges to is the variance of X. For example, a single sample mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})$ does not converge to $Var(X)$ since this is not its expected value.

Comment: @jefflovejapan P.S. You would ideally need to tighten your question to meet the standards of the site.  For example, in invoking CLT you're proposing a normal distribution for your estimators, but you seem to be interested only in the point estimates. Furthermore, as Dave says, the idea of "validity" is not statistically well-defined.  Some reading around statistical estimators, and different notions of convergence (e.g. I use the term "almost surely" above), should help.